# Facebook Pages Events Analytics data through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, analytics

I am trying to fetch "Events Analytics data" from a Facebook Pag, but I can't find an endpoint where its possible to fetch this data. The data I am trying to get is the Event Data related to Conversations / Messages.

The events listed here I want to access: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/page-analytics

I notice that Facebook Analytics are using AppEvents: event_name=fb_pages_messaging_message_received

Can anyone guide me in direction of the correct API endpoint or documentation?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export

Comment: Thanks @CBroe but do you know if the export is the only way? I did check that already but it can't work in the use-case that I am working on.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is the only way (apart from using the UI that Facebook has build around this directly, of course.)